# Decrypt data using private key in SSL context in openssl (ssl_st)

Tags: encryption, openssl, key, private

Is it possible to get the private key of a TLS session from the SSL* context variable? I have a string encrypted with the public key and I would like to decrypt it using the corresponding private key from an SSL* context.

I have tried this but is doesn't work:

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL);
EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, *out, &outlen, in, inlen)
```

where:
    `pkey` is `s->cert->key->privatekey` (s is an already existing SSL* variable in the TLS session)

`in/inlen` is the encrypted string,

`out/outlen` is the expected output.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, that code is actually working, it was just a problem with the padding.

I was calling:

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

As soon as I removed that line the decryption worked. I don't actully know why, anybody can explain how padding works? I mean, should I know what kind of padding has been used or I just can ignore it (i.e. remove the line)